# Where has my 'Research' option gone?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have just moved to my new office and hired my first employee, and now I want to do some research before I develop my next game engine but the option to research appears to have disappeared?

[image]

How can I research new game elements now that I have moved into my new office? Where has my 'Research' option gone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha! Found it - now that I have multiple employees (well, there are just two of us) the 'Research' option has disappeared from the main menu and now appears under a menu I get from clicking on my character:

[image]

It seems that it's possible to get each of your multiple employees to research different game elements simultaneously, so while I am researching branching stories, my other employee(s) can be researching something else... like stereo sounds.